# Merge Data frame in for loop

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

input: 6 CSV with different segment, Row 14 Stores different segment

Expected Output:Make a single csv(by appending 6 different CSV) which includes segment also.

```
library(stringr)
for (i in 1:6){
name<-paste("Page url - Fri.  1 May 2015 - Tue. 19 May 2015 ","(",i,")",".csv",sep="")
CSVlines <- readLines(name)
v1 <- str_extract_all(CSVlines[14], "\\w+")[[1]]
d1 <-read.csv(name,skip=22,header=TRUE)
df1<-cbind(d1, setNames(list(v1[2]), v1[1]))
}
```

Comment: What is your question? If you have different columns names, you could use `rbind.fill` from `plyr`.

Comment: All column name are same..adding only segment column ..Just want to union all 6 csv results

Comment: Do you want to join the columns? You could take a look at `Reduce`